# how to include view in lithium framework

Tags: php, lithium

I am using lithium framework to do my application because it supports mongodb ,

Now I am trouble with how to include another view file in a view file

For example I get a view file named 'menu.html.php'

```
<div id='menu'>
    <ul>
        <li>home</li><li>about</li><li>contact</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In my 'index.html.php' ,I want to inlude the above file so that I don't have to write the same code each time. So that's my solution

```
<?php 

$base = ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);

echo $this->render($base.'/app/views/meeting/mainmenu.html.php');
?>
```

I think there must be a better way to do that.Because every time I need to calculate the full view path.

I haven't yet find the answer in lithium's doc. 
Any helps would be thanks

Comment: Thanks for Chris ,that works fine ,Is there an example to show the usage about $this->_render('template')? I tried a lot but failed for the third args,if the first arg is template ,what's the meaning?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this in your view files to render elements:

```
<?= $this->_render('element', 'resources/list-single', compact('resource')); ?>
```

Will render the file 'app/views/elements/resources/list-single.html.php'. $resource will also be available in the sub-template.

Comment: For more info, see:
http://lithify.me/docs/lithium/template/view/Renderer::_render()

Comment: I submitted a pull request to the manual - https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/manual/pull/46