# Lithium framework template parts

Tags: templates, lithium

So here is my question :

How can I use template parts ? I mean individual files like navbar.html.php which I would include in my layout and passing parameters.

I did some researches but didn't found much about it ...

Thanks for reading/helping =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been added to the manual but please see [how to include view in lithium framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14698748/how-to-include-view-in-lithium-framework) for anwser. If you need more info please do ask!

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted !